# Is ROS/Turtlebot 2 compatible with any camera?

Tags: ros, usb-camera, logitech, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm fairly new to ROS so I apologize if this is an obvious question.  What restrictions, if any, does ROS and/or the turtlebot 2 have when it comes to camera compatibility?

I want to use a Logitech Quickcam Orbit AF found [here](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/quickcam-sphere-af) but it's a bit pricey so I don't want to buy it until I know for sure that I'll be able to use it.  It has a mic and can pan and tilt about its base automatically.  Will I be able to use these features as well?

Does anyone have experience using this type of camera or other cameras that don't necessarily have a lot of documentation?

What steps would I need to take in order to implement a new camera with ROS?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231473/is-ros/turtlebot-2-compatible-with-any-camera?/) by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS isn't one big monolithic thing that either does or does not have support for a particular piece of hardware. It's more nuanced than that.

ROS compatibility with cameras depends mostly on whether or not you can find a camera driver that supports the camera you're interested in. There are a few common camera drivers available for ROS that are listed elsewhere: http://answers.ros.org/question/9089/what-driver-should-i-use-for-my-usb-camera/ and http://www.iheartrobotics.com/2010/05/testing-ros-usb-camera-drivers.html

As for that specific camera, I've seen them on ROS robots in the past, so it seems like someone got the driver working at some point.

A [quick google search for "ros quickcam orbit"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ros%20quickcam%20orbit) turns up a number of open-source projects with drivers:

- https://github.com/Teknoman117/ucm-ros-pkg/blob/master/kybernetes_drivers/uvc_camera/src/node.cpp - not well documented but looks like it integrates the driver and control. uses the older rosbuild system, so might be a little out of date
- https://github.com/AndreaCensi/orbit_camera_actuator - simple, just does PTZ. updated for catkin, so has a slightly higher chance of working, but you'll need a separate node to acquire images.
- http://answers.ros.org/question/10365/using-the-player-package/ - an older answer on ROS Answers with users discussing this camera, with various drivers and links to source.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-04-09**:
Thanks for the links! Just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look to the ORBBEC Camera: http://www.robotnikstore.com/robotnik/5816243/orbbec-camera.html

https://github.com/orbbec/astra

---

Originally posted by [jperez](https://answers.ros.org/users/26623/jperez/) with karma: 11 on 2016-04-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-04-18**:
I've seen these in person and they seem like a good alternative to the Primesense devices.